# Isolating for multiple dark regions in an image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have multiple images with [darks bands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uu2H.jpg) and I want to draw a rectangle over all of the darker bands. I have tried using HSV color detection, it works reasonably well but it picks up darker regions [Current output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BNxg.png), code below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stretch = frames.copy() #Frame is the imported image
#Increasing the contrast of the image
# CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2., tileGridSize=(8,8))
lab = cv2.cvtColor(stretch, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # convert from BGR to LAB color space
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  # split on 3 different channels

l2 = clahe.apply(l)  # apply CLAHE to the L-channel

lab = cv2.merge((l2,a,b))  # merge channels
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # convert from LAB to BG


# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)

img2 = cv2.cvtColor(smooth,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

frame_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
frame_threshold = cv2.inRange(frame_HSV, (0, 0, 10), (180, 255, 80))
contours,hierarchy, = cv2.findContours(frame_threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
sorted_areas = np.sort(areas)
#cnt=contours[areas.index(sorted_areas[-1])] #the biggest contour
largestContourArea = sorted_areas[-1]*0.1
largestContour = 0
for cnt in contours:
    contourArea = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if( contourArea > largestContourArea):
        #cv2.drawContours(frames, cnt, -1, (255,0,132), thickness=4) 
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(frames, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 4)
        
        ROI = frames[y:y+h,x:x+w]     
        plt.imshow(ROI)
        plt.show()
cv2.drawContours(frames, contours, -1, (0,150,132), thickness=4) 
plt.imshow(frames)
plt.show()
```

[Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCfFS.png)

I have tried Canny detection but I couldn't get it to work, I do have limited experience with it. Is there another way to draw a box around the dark bands?

Comment: hsv isn't "wrong" but superfluous here. you have a quasi-grayscale image. imread with IMREAD_GRAYSCALE. it would help if you could post the image output from your script.

Comment: Also, please provide an image showing how you want the output to look. Based on the input image I can't tell if you're hoping to see 2, 3, 4, or more rectangles (unique dark bands).

Comment: So my code working and outlining the all of the dark bands but just right now I changed something and I can't get it work again. I will show the output of my code as soon as I can get it working. But I have uploaded an hand drawn version of the output I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otsu thresholding does a pretty good job of that image. IMHO, there's little point converting a near-grey to HSL as there is no colour, so I load it as greyscale:

```
import cv2

# Load as greyscale - no colour anyway
im = cv2.imread('9uu2H.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Otsu threshold
_, thr = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Note: I cropped off your black border because I didn't want to confuse Otsu thresholding with an additional, third class of grey, i.e. black.

Note: I added a red border artificially so you can see the extent on Stack Overflow's background.

Note: You can add blurring, or filtering, or morphology to fill holes to taste.

[image]

Comment: I thought using HSV for a gray scale did not make much sense. But I thought using inRange and setting the bounds above 0 in the V channel would ignore the black border. I need to keep the entire image